# Image of an open set under an injective immersion map is Borel measurable?

Tags: measure-theory, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Let $M$ and $N$ be two smooth manifolds and $f:M\to N$ be an injective immersion. Let $U\subset M$ be an open subset, then is $f(U)$ necessarily a Borel measurable subset of $N$?

Comment: Are manifolds necessarily second countable in the definition you use?

Comment: Yes, we assume that

Comment: Then $U$ is $\sigma$-compact and mere continuity of $f$ suffices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just cover U with open subsets where f is an imbedding.  Then f(U) is a countable union of borel measurable sets

Edit: Daniel’s answer in the comments is obviously better

Comment: You mean an immersion is locally an embedding?

Comment: Yes, tho Daniels answer is obviously better if all you care about is measurability

Comment: The key fact I didn't remember is that immersion is locally an embedding, so your answer addresses my issue most

Comment: I can't drop the condition of immersion, right? Which implies f has to be smooth